# If my object is produced by a producer method, will its initializer methods be called automatically?

Tags: cdi, jsr299

I have a producer method that creates instances of—let's say—`Person`.

The instance that this method creates is of type `PersonBean` and quite obviously implements `Person`.

This class has an initializer method in it:

```
@Inject
public void setSomething(final Something something) {
  // whatever
}
```

There is also a `Something` implementation on the classpath in a bean archive that should be a candidate for injecting here.

I've observed that this implementation is injected into an appropriately-annotated field of another non-producer-method-produced object, so I know Weld is finding it, it's valid, etc. etc.

The specification is not clear (to me) on whether or not my producer method's return value will then *also* have Weld/container-provided dependency injection applied to it.

I am certainly observing that this initializer method is not called automatically.

Boiled down, my question is: if I am producing an object, then does that mean my producer method must take care of *all* initialization of that object, or (what I'd expect instead) is my producer method *only* responsible for instantiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I am producing an object, then does that mean my producer method
>   must take care of all initialization of that object, or (what I'd
>   expect instead) is my producer method only responsible for
>   instantiation?

[From the spec:](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#producermethod)

```
3.3. Producer methods
    A producer method acts as a source of objects to be injected, where:
    - the objects to be injected are not required to be instances of beans,
```

This should answer your question: If you are instantiating **a new object** (using `new`) you will have to take care of the initialization.

(A probably more common usecase of producer methods is to configure and produce **an existing bean** into a certain scope...)

Comment: I believe you; I'm not sure why that spec snippet should answer my question. Perhaps a producer method (this is what I was trying to figure out) takes care of the initial instantiation, and then perhaps its return value is then passed through the rest of the CDI DI mechanism.

If I read you right, you're saying it might be better to have the instance be passed in as a `@New` in the producer method (in my case) and then mess with its innards?